# An error ocurred while calculating Code Metrics in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, code-metrics

I have Office 2007 (and Excel 2007) installed in my Windows XP sp3, and I use VSTS 2008 Team Suite.

I execute option Code Metrics about a csproj in my solution, and I get the error:

```
An error ocurred while calculating Code Metrics
```

How can I debug it? What happened?

Answer (score 3):

You are most likely missing a reference in your project. There are two posts that deal exactly with your problem that might help you:

- [Error when running calculate code
  metrics](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/aa9aa501-50d6-415e-af99-f65da59e4c63)
- [Bug found in calculating Code
  Metrics in VS2008](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2007/12/21/bug-found-in-calculating-code-metrics-in-vs2008.aspx)